# Re-assembling split file names with Powershell

Tags: powershell, parsing

I'm having trouble re-assembling certain filenames (and discarding the rest) from a text file. The filenames are split up (usually on three lines) and there is always a blank line after each filename. I only want to keep filenames that begin with `OPEN` or `FOUR`. An example is:

```
OPEN.492820.EXTR
A.STANDARD.38383
333

FOUR.383838.282.
STAND.848484.NOR
MAL.3939

CLOSE.3480384.ST
ANDARD.39393939.
838383
```

The output I'd like would be:

```
OPEN.492820.EXTRA.STANDARD.38383333
FOUR.383838.282.STAND.848484.NORMAL.3939
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Where are you getting the input data from? A file?

Comment: Yes, just a simple text file (edited)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked for me, you can give it a try.

- See https://regex101.com/r/JuzXOb/1 for the [`Regex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=net-6.0) explanation.

```
$source = 'fullpath/to/inputfile.txt'
$destination = 'fullpath/to/resultfile.txt'

[regex]::Matches(
    (Get-Content $source -Raw),
    '(?msi)^(OPEN|FOUR)(.*?|\s*?)+([\r\n]$|\z)'
).Value.ForEach({ -join($_ -split '\r?\n').ForEach('Trim') }) |
Out-File $destination
```

**For testing:**

```
$txt = @'
OPEN.492820.EXTR
A.STANDARD.38383
333

FOUR.383838.282.
STAND.848484.NOR
MAL.3939

CLOSE.3480384.ST
ANDARD.39393939.
838383

OPEN.492820.EXTR
A.EXAMPLE123

FOUR.383838.282.
STAND.848484.123
ZXC
'@

[regex]::Matches(
    $txt,
    '(?msi)^(OPEN|FOUR)(.*?|\s*?)+([\r\n]$|\z)'
).Value.ForEach({ -join($_ -split '\r?\n').ForEach('Trim') })
```

**Output:**

```
OPEN.492820.EXTRA.STANDARD.38383333
FOUR.383838.282.STAND.848484.NORMAL.3939
OPEN.492820.EXTRA.EXAMPLE123
FOUR.383838.282.STAND.848484.123ZXC
```

Comment: Thank you, that's pretty close. For me, i'm only getting the first line of each filename though. It's also adding a blank line in between each, that's not a big deal.

Comment: @yodish Are you sure the `-Raw` is there on your code? Does the text look like the one on the regex101 link from me answer?

Comment: @santiago_squarzon I appreciate it! Unfortunately, your test is still only outputting the 1st line of each for me. Yes, `-RAW` is in the first code I ran. Maybe, something isn't resolving correctly from a copy/paste...I will keep looking into it.

Comment: @yodish I suspect this is because after every line there is a lot of white spaces, for example `A.STANDARD.38383           `. I updated the answer, try again, hopefully that works.

Comment: `A.STANDARD.38383<space><space><space>`

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, I ended up finding another non-powershell solution. I think you are correct about the white space; but, i'm still getting that first line, using your test. It may be something on my end. I really appreciate the help! I will mark this as the answer.

Comment: @yodish thank you for accepting the answer, I would love to help you but it's hard to tell what could be the issue without having the original file at hand. If you copy paste the content of your file on the regex101 link I provided, do you see the right pattern being match or does the same issue happen (only first line being matched)?

Answer (score 0):

Read the file one line at a time and keep concatenating them until you encounter a blank line, at which point you output the concatenated string and repeat until you reach the end of the file:

```
# this variable will keep track of the partial file names
$fileName = ''

# use a switch to read the file and process each line
switch -Regex -File ('path\to\file.txt') {
  # when we see a blank line...
  '^\s*$' {
    # ... we output it if it starts with the right word
    if($s -cmatch '^(OPEN|FOUR)'){ $fileName }
    # and then start over
    $fileName = ''
  }

  default {
    # must be a non-blank line, concatenate it to the previous ones
    $s += $_
  }
}

# remember to check and output the last one
if($s -cmatch '^(OPEN|FOUR)'){
  $fileName
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Dumb question; but, what is the best way to pipe the output to a text file? | OUT-FILE ?

Comment: `Out-File` will work, so will `Set-Content`. E.g. paste the code in my answer into a file `join-filenames.ps1` and then run `join-filenames.ps1 |Set-Content .\output.txt` in the correct folder

Comment: Hmm, i'm successfully writing output to a text file now (using out-file, rather than set-content); but, getting an empty file.